# How to track a caller for native getters / setters of host objects in a browser?

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser, getter-setter, host-object

Here is a use case:

Assume we have a web page that has an issue, which results in the page to be scrolled up on a mobile device at some point after **DOMContentLoaded** has fired.

We can legitimately assume there is something, which operates on **document.documentElement.scrollTop** (e.g. assigns it a value of **0**).

Suppose we also know there are hundreds of places, where this can happen.

To debug the issue we can think of the following strategies:

- check each event handler, which can set a value of 0 **scrollTop**, one by one
- try to use [debug](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#function) function available in Chrome DevTools
- Override a native scrollTop as:

```js
var scrollTopOwner = document.documentElement.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__;
var oldDescr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(scrollTopOwner, 'scrollTop');
Object.defineProperty(scrollTopOwner, '_oldScrollTop_', oldDescr);
Object.defineProperty(scrollTopOwner, 'scrollTop', {
  get:function(){
    return this._oldScrollTop_;
  },
  set: function(v) {
    debugger;
    this._oldScrollTop_ = v;
  }
});

function someMethodCausingAPageToScrollUp() {
  document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 1e3;
}

setTimeout(someMethodCausingAPageToScrollUp, 1000);
```

The issue with the second approach is that it doesn't work with native getters/setters.

The issue with the third approach is that even though now we can easily track what is assigning a value to the **scrollTop** property, we monkey patch a native getters/setters and risk to cause unnecessary side effects.

Hence the question: is there a more elegant solution to debug native getters and setters for web browser host objects (e.g. document, window, location, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is possible to use `debug` function for `set` method on a `scrollTop` property descriptor.

The code is as follows:

```js
debug(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'scrollTop').set);
```

After that, we'll automatically stop in any function that tries to set a value to `scrollTop`.
If you need to automatically stop only on those functions which assign a value within a certain threshold (for example, between 0 and 500), you can easily do that too since `debug` function accepts a second argument (condition) where you can specify your condition logic.

For example:

```js
// In that case, we'll automatically stop only in those functions which assign scrollTop a value within a range of [1, 499] inclusively
debug(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'scrollTop').set, 'arguments[0] > 0 && arguments[0] < 500');
```

Pros:

- easy to use and doesn't require a lot of boilerplate code

Cons:

- you'll have to evaluate that js snippet above each time when you refresh your page

Many thanks to [Aleksey Kozyatinskiy](https://twitter.com/ak_239) (former Googler on DevTools team) for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
const collector = [];
const originalScrollTop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'scrollTop');
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'scrollTop', {
    get: () => originalScrollTop.get.call(document.scrollingElement),
    set: function(v) {
        collector.push((new Error()).stack)
        originalScrollTop.set.call(document.scrollingElement, v)
    }
})
```

You can collect stacktraces and inspect them later. We don't log it immediately to not cause IO delays.
Works in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, however, that is not quite what I was expecting to see.
The proposed approach is shorter in terms of lines of code but altogether with approach #2 from the post description they both are custom-made solutions, which forces a developer to keep that among browser snippets.
I wonder if there is a native (built-in) way (even behind an experimental feature) to debug (e.g. put a breakpoint, inspect a call stack, see a caller, etc) getters/setters.